# Test failures for tezos-p2p on FreeBSD, kern.maxfiles limit exceeded

Tags: testing, p2p

Tezos on FreeBSD

Running atop a freshly ported Ocaml 4.09.1 that passes tests.

Tezos tests fail for tezos-p2p (cannot bind to listening socket) due to too many file descriptors open.

By watching sysctl kern.openfiles during the tezos-p2p test, it shows pre-test use of 230 fds, and in-test use of over 891000.

I'm new to Ocaml. Any assistance to debug this issue is most welcome.

Comment: What is `tezos-p2p`? That's not a binary that comes with the code AFAIK.

Comment: It is the "public_name" value from src/lib_p2p/dune, and corresponds to the directory _build/install/default/lib/tezos-p2p

Comment: Make sure you are on most recent code checkout hash: 06398944

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are on most recent code checkout hash: `$ git log -1` should give you the hash: 0639894412 (Feb 11 2020)

I just did a complete rebuild of the source and I do not have `tezos-p2p` in the path you specified.  This, `$ find ./ -iname tezos-p2p`, returns no results in the entire code tree.

Additionally, looking at the build file (dune file) it says this is a library, not a binary to be executed. The core binaries are built in the root source directory, not within _build.

These are the only binaries to be ran: `tezos-accuser-005-PsBabyM1 tezos-accuser-006-PsCARTHA tezos-admin-client tezos-baker-005-PsBabyM1 tezos-baker-006-PsCARTHA tezos-client tezos-codec tezos-endorser-005-PsBabyM1 tezos-endorser-006-PsCARTHA tezos-node tezos-protocol-compiler tezos-signer tezos-validator`

Comment: On advice from Tezos, I'm working from the master branch. I pulled from commit 5d50f7a5ab400ae857c0478fa29fa135954fb6ba from March 31.

Comment: On advice from Tezos, I'm working from the master branch. I pulled from commit 5d50f7a5ab400ae857c0478fa29fa135954fb6ba from March 31.



The tezos-p2p is not an executable, but a test target name from their Makefile (full target is tezos-p2p.test).



My run of your find commands gives me
./_build/install/default/lib/tezos-p2p



Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ok. So my answer above of making sure you are on the correct git checkout is valid then? That test target must only exist on the `master` branch and not on the `mainnet` branch then. If above is good, please mark as answered. Thanks.

Comment: The issue was an unstated dependency on IPv6, which was not enabled on the host.

Answer (score 1):

The code uses IPv6, which must be enabled on the host, and was not in my case.

Comment: Very odd. IPV6 is not enabled on any of my nodes (Ubuntu/CentOS) and they've been tezos operational for over 1.5yrs. Must be a FreeBSD thing.

Comment: The test code assumes that ipv6 to ipv4 mapping is enabled. It is not by default on FreeBSD, even when ipv6 is enabled. Once mapping is enabled the tests pass.